# CSS styling for different languages

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using translatepress plugin for the translation. The page is in English by default. How can I use a different css style for a different language? The below doesn't work.

```
:lang(zh_CN) {
   font-family: 'Noto Sans SC', sans-serif!important;
   font-size:16px!important;
}

html[lang="zh_CN"] table.variations{
    font-size:30px!important;
}

html[lang="zh_CN"] table.variations ul li p{
    font-size:30px!important;
}
```

Comment: Found the solution. For the plugin, it uses its own selector  `.translatepress-YOUR-LANGUAGE`. For e.g. in my case will be `.translatepress-zh_CN` Hope it helps someone out there

Comment: Please write an answer